# Achieving declared Cloud Bigtable writes QPS

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

We've setup Bigtable cluster with 5 nodes, and GCP console states that it should support 50K QPS @ 6ms for reads and writes.

We are trying to load a large dataset (~800M records) with ~50 fields containing mostly numeric data, and a few short strings. The keys are 11-digit numeric strings.

When loading this dataset via HBase API from a single client VM in GCE we observe up to 4K QPS when putting each field into a separate column. We use single HBase connection, and multiple threads (5-30) doing batch puts of 10K records.

When combining all fields into a single column (Avro-encoded, ~250 bytes per record), the write performance with batch puts improves to 10K QPS. Number of concurrent threads doesn't seem to affect QPS. When using a separate HBase connection per thread, write performance increases to 20K QPS with 5 threads.

The client VM is in the same availability zone as Bigtable cluster, and it stays almost idle during the load, so it doesn't look like the bottleneck is on the client side.

Questions:

1. From our tests it appears that write QPS decreases with the number of columns inserted. Is this expected, and how can this relationship be quantified? (BTW, it'd be great if this was mentioned in [Bigtable performance documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance)).
2. What may we be missing in order to achieve the declared write QPS? My understanding is that each cluster node should support 10K write QPS, however it appears that we are going against a single node with a single HBase connection, and only against 2 nodes with multiple HBase connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BufferedMutator` in 0.2.3-SNAPSHOT with OpenSSL and Java8 gives 22-23K QPS for small (1KB) mutations on 4 CPU machines and up to 90K on a 32 CPU machine.  0.2.2 gave 10K-12K QPS.  Open a single HBase connection for best performance.

**Note - removed note about OpenSSL as it's now the default**

See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client for additional info.

Comment: Thanks Les! Looks like that github repo is private. Can this test be published in a public repo?

Comment: I'll try to get it done with the 0.2.3 release -- sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the second question: we managed to get to over 50K QPS by switching from batch HBase Puts to [mutators](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/master/java/dataflow-pardo-helloworld/src/main/java/com/example/bigtable/dataflow/pardo/HelloWorldBigtablePardo.java#L97). We are still using multiple HBase connections, single connection appears to be limited to single node throughput.

Comment: We fixed the single connection issue in the upcoming 0.2.3 release.  The 0.2.3-SNAPSHOT (at http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots) can get the same throughput from a single Connection.